# Sencha Touch custom back button

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to create a custom back button for a nestedlist. In my controller I have created a listener to capture the button tap event as follows:

```
onCustomButtonBackTap: function(button, e, options) {
        this.getMyList().setDepth(node.data.depth-1); <-- seudo code, does not work
    },
```

My question is how can I set the current level of my nestedlist back by one each time the custom button is clicked? Also, if this approach is not correct, please let me know

Thanks is advance for your help and advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the current active item to set the new one... you need to use the methods in my sample code below to accomplish what you are looking for:

```
var newIndex = this.getMyList().getActiveItem();
this.getMyList().setActiveItem(newIndex-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff, thank you for your answer but I found the following method which works better in my circumstance

```
onCustomButtonBackTap: function(button, e, options) {
        if (this.getMyList().items.indexOf(this.getMyList().getActiveItem()) > 0) {
        this.getMyList().onBackTap();
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hi Arkady, how did you create custom back button for nested list? Please help me, i am also in need of custom back button for nested list.